# Special characters in HTML

Tags: html, ios, unicode, playing-cards, character-entities

I am creating html page for iOS,where i need to put " ♠, ♥, ♦, and ♣ ".
These are the cards symbols.

But since this is not normal text, the text on the iPhone is coming up as unusual text.
please suggest me html code for using these symbols in my html code.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What *didn't* work?

Comment: Just check this link
[http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-gui-icons/demo/](http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-gui-icons/demo/)

Comment: Use the HTML entities codes form the other answers, or use images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
&spades;    ♠   Spade card suit
&clubs;         ♣   Clubs card suit
&diams;         ♦   Diamonds card suit
&hearts;    ♥   Hearts card suit
```

Answer (score 4):

If you put characters like ♠, ♥, ♦, and ♣ into an HTML document, you need to make sure that the declared encoding of the document coincides with the actual encoding. Normally, the encoding should be UTF-8. See the W3C document [Declaring character encodings in HTML](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations).

Using entity references like `&spades;` *circumvents* the problem, but the *solution* is to fix the encoding issue. What if there are *other* special characters, now or after next edit of the document. And a character need not be any more special than the simple curly apostrophe (’) to create encoding issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the equivalent html entities ♥`&hearts;` ♠`&spades;` ♣`&clubs;` ♦`&diams;`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following:

```
♠   &#9824;
♣   &#9827;
♥   &#9829;
♦   &#9830;
```

Got the codes from [this reference page.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_symbols.asp)